# From file of path to unique data structure

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm reading from a file a list of paths. I want to save them in a built-in java structure that can erase the duplicates automatically. By duplicates I mean if I have `/usr/bin` and then I add `/usr` the `bin` folder has to be erased because is "contained" inside the `usr` folder. I read the file sequentially so I'd prefer to not have to check all data twice, if possible.

Example code:

```
UnknownType<Path> database;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("db.txt")));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    Path path = Paths.get(line).toRealPath();
    database.add(path);
}
```

Example file:

```
/usr/bin
/usr
/dev
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/home/user/Desktop/file.txt
/home/user/Documents/file2.txt
/home/user/Documents/file3.txt
```

Expected output:

```
data structure containing paths: 
/usr
/dev
/home/user/Desktop/file.txt
/home/user/Documents/file2.txt
/home/user/Documents/file3.txt
```

Comment: So you only want top-level folders in your data structure? Strip off anything after the second slash and store the data in a `Set`.

Comment: Can be files too and not only on top level folder, I'll modify the question better

Comment: I don't quite understand your requirement. Do you mean that if the path corresponds to a file, you want to include it as-is; if the path is a folder, only include the top-level?

Comment: I believe the database should contain no paths that are subpaths of another in the database, and conflicts should be resolved by choosing the higher-level path.

Comment: @MickMnemonic It doesn't matter if it's a file or not. If I insert after `/home`, `/home/user` or `/home/user/Desktop` one of this should erase the file. Obviously, on the other hand, a file will never erase a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tree-based solution (probably more efficient):

```
class Database {

  public void add(String p) {
    root.add(Arrays.asList(p.split("\\\\|/")), 0);
  }

  public void addAll(Collection<? extends String> list) {
    for (String p : list)
    add(p);
  }

  public List<String> getPathsList() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    root.listPaths(list, "");
    return list;
  }

  PathNode root = new PathNode("");

  static class PathNode {

    public final String name;
    public Map<String, PathNode> children = new HashMap<>();

    public PathNode(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf() {
      return children.size()==0;
    }

    public boolean isRoot() {
      return name.isEmpty();
    }

    public void add(List<String> path, int i) {
      String childName = path.get(i);
      PathNode child = children.get(childName);

      if (child != null) {
        if (path.size()-i <= 1) child.children.clear();
        else child.add(path, i+1);
      } else if (!isLeaf() || isRoot()) {
        PathNode node = this;
        for (; i < path.size(); i++) {
          String key = path.get(i);
          node.children.put(key, node = new PathNode(key));
        }
      }
    }

    public void listPaths(ArrayList<String> list, String prefix) {
      for (PathNode child : children.values()) {
        if (child.isLeaf()) list.add(prefix+child.name);
        else child.listPaths(list, prefix+child.name+File.separator);
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Test to verify correctness: http://ideone.com/cvqEVT

This implementation will accept both Windows and Unix paths when running on any platform. The paths returned by `Database.getPathsList()` will still use the OS's file separator; you could change that by changing `File.separator` in `Database.PathNode.listPaths` (the last line of real code).

Comment: If it's not much to ask, could you make it os-indipendent?

Comment: Updated answer and ideone, no longer uses `java.nio.file.Path`. Tested with your Unix paths and with Windows paths.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
class Database {

  public void add(Path p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
      Path p2 = paths.get(i);
      if (p2.startsWith(p)) {
        // replace with new path
        paths.set(i, p);
        return;
      }
      if (p.startsWith(p2)) {
        // don't add this new one
        return;
      }
    }
    // else, add the new one
    paths.add(p);
  }

  ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

`LinkedList` implementation:

```
class Database {

  public void add(Path p) {
    for (ListIterator<Path> it = paths.listIterator(0); it.hasNext();) {
      Path p2 = it.next();
      if (p2.startsWith(p)) {
        // replace with new path
        it.set(p);
        return;
      }
      if (p.startsWith(p2)) {
        // don't add this new one
        return;
      }
    }
    // else, add the new one
    paths.add(p);
  }

  LinkedList<Path> paths = new LinkedList<>();

}
```

Comment: I think this idea could work. But I was actually looking for a data structure that doesn't need to check all the paths already loaded. (and hopefully without needing to create a class to handle it)

Comment: But the way that you change the database when adding a new element is based off of the current entries in the database, right? So you would have to check the contents somehow. It could be more efficient with indexing.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question but If i do, the answer is yes. My initial idea was to implement a tree so i only needed to check if the folders in the path were leaves on every add. So I don't need to check every folder in the database variable. But i'm not that sure it's viable, and I don't even know the right java structure to implement it.

Comment: I see what you mean. That would probably be more efficient for long lists. I'll post another answer in a min

Comment: I don't think you could easily do this without implementing a custom class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that even if you represented it as a tree, you'd have to touch every entry when you add. The tree would just be a list, because according to your constraints, there wouldn't be any "branching" (no node other than the root node could have more than one child)

Comment: /home/user/Desktop/file.txt and /home/user/Documents/file2.txt the user node has 2 childs, am I wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120181/discussion-between-umuril-lyerood-and-qxz).

Answer (score 0):

```
static ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();

public static void main (String[]args) { 
    add(Paths.get("/usr/bin"));
    add(Paths.get("/usr"));
    add(Paths.get("/dev"));
    add(Paths.get("/dev/sda"));
    add(Paths.get("/home/user/Desktop/file.txt"));
    System.out.println(paths.toString());
} 

public static void add(Path path){
    // get root
    String firstDir = path.subpath(0, 1).toString();
    // check all known paths
    for (int q = 0; q < paths.size(); q++){
        Path p = paths.get(q);
        // get root of saved path
        String pFirstDir = p.subpath(0, 1).toString();

        // do they have the same root path
        if (pFirstDir.equals(firstDir)){
            // the new path needs to have less folders otherwise return
            if (path.getNameCount()>p.getNameCount()){
                return;
            }

            // set the new path and return
            paths.set(q, path);
            return;
        }
    }
    // no paths found taht match so add
    paths.add(path);
}
```

will print:

```
[\usr, \dev, \home\user\Desktop\file.txt]
```